# Why get I this error message with this package?

Tags: python, import, module, package

My package, which is on https://pypi.org/project/lucapackage/ doesn't work.
The code in the package is:

```
def add_numbers(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract_numbers(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply_numbers(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def divide_numbers(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2
```

The error message, which I got on my file was:

NameError: name 'add_numbers' is not defined

The code which this error message generates is:

```
import lucapackage
print(add_numbers(9,8))
```

Comment: do `lucapackage.add_numbers(9, 8)` or `from lucapackage import add_numbers`

Answer (score 0):

first you need to uninstall it,

```
pip uninstall lucapackage
```

then again install this,

```
pip install lucapackage
```

the code is working:
[image]

Comment: I still get the error message. But with: "from lucapackage import add_numbers" it works